# Deferring Execution Till Needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

I know that you use jQuery deferreds in the following scenario:

I have a asynchronous request. I'd like to execute one or more sections of code whenever this request comes back.

Here's my issue. I don't want the async request to actually be sent out until it hits the first .when statement.

For instance:

I have an init function that loads up say 50 different deferred objects for various data requests. I obviously don't want all of these to fire at once, just when needed. The data will be loaded (the deferred object resolved) on future .when statements.

Sort of complicated but thanks for reading this! :D

Here's what we have

init() = function {
    var data1 = someDeferredRequest();
    //blah, lots of these
}

.doSomethingElse() = function {
    //I only want the call to data1 to have been started the first instance I try to go get it, like this instance below. I do NOT want it fired in the init
    $.when(data1).then();

```
 //other stuff, still want data1 to be completed by here
 $.when(data1).then();
```

}

Comment: Can you add some of the code that you tried?  That will help other people see where the issue is.  Or at least it will help me :)

Comment: Attach a callback to whatever event will trigger your call? I may not be understanding how you have your dependencies chained.

Comment: Added some code for clarification. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Have a method on the objects named `fire()` or `run()`, whatever suits you that grabs/pulls does whatever you want with the data.

The object will then sit idle until you call `object.run()`.